# Convert String to NSDate when using DatePicker and TextField

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I'm using a textfield that uses a datePicker instead of a keyboard. It displays the format as a string that looks like this 'May 31, 2015 at 12:30'(taken from the println(delivery.text) function.) I want to change the date to NSDate, so I can compare to current date. Any suggestions?

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickUp: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var delivery: UITextField!
let dateFormat: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
let dateFormat2: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let datePicker2: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    dateFormat.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("updateDateField:"), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    pickUp.inputView = datePicker

    dateFormat2.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    dateFormat2.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    datePicker2.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
    datePicker2.addTarget(self, action: Selector("updateDateField:"), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    delivery.inputView = datePicker2


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
}

func updateDateField(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    if sender == datePicker
    {
        pickUp.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }
    if sender == datePicker2
    {
        delivery.text = dateFormat2.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't need to change again, just save sender.date in a property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy 'at' h:mm:ss a"
if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("May 31, 2015 at 12:30:15 PM") {
  println(date)
}
```

if you need some reference for date formatting you can use this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the DateFormatter to format your string into a date and then pulling the NSDate object out like so. In your case, something like this would probably suit your needs.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy at H:mm"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(//insert string here)
```

Refer to the [original documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) if you have further questions or this [handy guide](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/) for formatting guidelines.

Comment: I tried that but when I println(date) it is returning 'nil'. The format of the date is 'May 31, 2015 at 12:30:15 PM' and I tried using "MMMM d, yyyy at H:mm:ss" but that did not work either.

Comment: I have a feeling that it's the "at" causing the problems. Maybe try to substring that part out and then feed it into the DateFormatter.